# Windows 10 not uninstalling software correctly

Tags: windows-10

I had DU Meter and Rainmeter installed on my system. Uninstalled them the correct way.

Now I keep finding traces of those programs in places like: [image]

Any idea how I can remove it fully?

Comment: Have you restarted the PC?

Comment: Yes, a few times already.

Comment: I suppose its up to the authors uninstaller to take care of this, really cannot blame Microsoft, but would like to.

Comment: Can you hop into this place in the registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify  and see if "IconStreams" and "PastIconsStream" exists there? Ccleaner should be dealing with that.   If you want to test you could export that whole Key as a Backup, then delete both of those.. Then you probably have to do an actual reboot for the registry to be saved out of ram, and that stuff reset on when the system runs again.  That May be the step missed when cleaning with CCleaner, but i dont know with 10 yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download). Uncheck everything except "Tray Notification Cache" under the "Advanced" section. After the cleaning, restart the explorer.exe process (or restart the computer).

[image]

Comment: Just tried this. It didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Like in Windows 8.1, apps can be removed via PowerShell utilizing remove-appxpackage. Step-By-Step details can be found here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/01/16/step-by-step-removing-windows-8-1-modern-apps-with-powershell.aspx